# What MSBuild condition should be used to detect target OS?

Tags: msbuild, csproj

What Condition Expression for PropertyGroup/ItemGroup should be used to differ target OS (`-r` argument of `dotnet publish`)? E.g. on these commands:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x86 --self-contained false
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-arm --self-contained false
```

Currently I've forced to use different Configurations and build using these commands:

```
dotnet publish -c ReleaseWin32 -r win-x86 --self-contained false
dotnet publish -c ReleaseLinux -r linux-arm --self-contained false
```

I know that MSBuild can define even target .NET Core/Framework version (e.g.`Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp3.1'"`), so probably should also define target OS (something like `Condition="'$(TargetOS)' == 'win-x86'"`).

Does there may be somehow used direct detection of target OS in CSPROJ file without using `-c ReleaseWin32` / `-c ReleaseLinux` for builds for different platforms? Shortly, does MSBuild syntax have any Condition about target OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLI's `-r linux-arm` translates to MSBUild `-property:RuntimeIdentifier=linux-x64` so you can use `$(RuntimeIdentifier)` in conditions:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'linux-arm'">
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="$(RuntimeIdentifier.StartsWith('win'))">
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Anyone knows why a Condition based on `RuntimeIdentifier` is not honored when using Publish from within Visual Studio? It seems to always be windows, and messing up the build that's published.